# Highlighting the first row in a table via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have logic for cells in a row to be highlighted when the first cell text is clicked working just fine. When the page loads however, I want to default the first row to be highlighted as the first row is displaying some other data based on it's id.

What works when the first cell text (id) is clicked is:

```
$("#simHeaderTable").find("tr").each(function () {
    var tdID = $(this).find("td:first-child").text();
    if (tdID == ID)
        $(this).children("td").css("background-color", "#FFFF66");
    else
        $(this).children("td").removeAttr("style");
});
```

So my logic was that this finds all rows and loops over them. I checked the first cell in each row and if the cells text is equal to some id I "highlight" it with some css. I unhighlight all the others.

So now inside document ready to highlight the first row on page load I figured I would just do the following, which doesn't result in anything getting highlighted.

```
$("#simHeaderTable").find("tr:first-child").children("td").css("background-color", "#FFFF66");
```

To me, this finds the first tr/row and then finds all children that are cells/td and applies the css to set the background color to yellow. Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: What is your html? Any errors in the console? [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jscbuaqp/) works fine with the code provided.

Comment: You are correct that it works. Had this before I did some setup of the table which I used fixheadertable jquery addon, which must have been clearing my formatting. Moved it to after this fixheadertable setup and now it works. Thanks for the double check.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is much more complex than needed, instead of:

```
$("#simHeaderTable").find("tr:first-child").children("td").css("background-color", "#FFFF66");
```

try:

```
$("#simHeaderTable tr:first-child > td").css("background-color", "#FFFF66");
```

You can even leave out the '>' unless you have nested tables.

Usually, you only use .find() when you have a cached selector like:

```
var cached_obj = $('#something');
// lots of code
var cached_obj.find('.something_else');
```